# How to work out modular arithmetic quickly for cryptography

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am not so good at Mathematics so please kindly forgive my stupidity.

Basically, I am learning modular arithmetic for cryptography and so I am struggling in understanding how to do big modular arithmetic calculation without a calculator.

So for example, how would I do this question: `6^56 mod 19`?

I get that you need to convert the power `56` into binary - so that would be `0111000`. So like `2^32` + `2^16` + `2^8`.

I then understand you have to do like:

`6^8 mod 19` then `6^16 mod 19` and `6^32 mod 19`.

I've been told I can use the *chinese remainder theorem* - but I want to know how to do this all.

Any help would be absolutely great! I like this stuff but I have been struggling a bit.

Comment: Please don't use phrases like 'kindly forgive my stupidity', no question is stupid and adding that is simply redundant and doesn't put you in a very good light. That said, Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!

Comment: CRT can be used when the modulus has more than one prime factor.. But your modulus $19$ is prime, so CRT won't help.

Answer (score 0):

What you mention you have to perform is the *fast exponentiation algorithm*.  However, usually one performs reductions  that rest on *Fermat's little theorem* (or *Euler's theorem* if the modulus is composite). Here, it is particularly efficient:

As $6$ and the modulus are coprime, we  know the $6^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$, so that
$$6^{56}\equiv 6^{56\bmod 18}=6^2\pmod{19},$$
therefore $\;6^{56}\equiv 36\equiv-2\:$ (or $17)\pmod{19}$.

Comment: I'm so lost now :S. Why did you or how do you know that `6^18 = 1 (mod 19)`??

Comment: That what  *lil' Fermat* asserts.

Comment: Where did the `18` come from

Comment: The general formula is that if $p$ is prime and $a$ is not divisible by $p$, then $\;a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$.

Comment: So which one is `a` and which one is `p`?

Comment: Here? $a=6$ and $p=19$.